# how do you solve $1.08=(1+x)^{1200}$?

Tags: quadratics

How do you solve $$1.08=(1+x)^{1200}?$$ Thanks so much for any guidance.

Comment: $\log 1.08 = 1200 \log(1+x)$

Comment: @StevenGregory $\log$ is unnecessary. Just take a root.

Comment: $x= \sqrt[1200]{1.08} -1$.

Comment: $x=-1 \pm \sqrt[1200]{1.08}$ because $1200$ is even. These are the real solutions.

Comment: @ZacharySelk - Sorry, I still think in terms of slide rules.

Answer (score 7):

Computing an approximation by hand. We have
$$
x=(1+0.08)^{1/1200}-1.
$$
Using the Taylor expansion $(1+x)^a=1+a\,x+O(x^2)$ we can approximate the answer as
$$
x\approx\frac{0.08}{1200}=\frac{1}{15000}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$\log(1.08)=\log\left((1+x)^{1200}\right)=1200\log(1+x)$$

so

$$\log(1+x)=\frac{\log(1.08)}{1200}$$

finally,

$$x=\exp\left(\frac{\log(1.08)}{1200}\right)-1\approx 6.41\cdot 10^{-5}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You're (all) missing the second solution

$$x=\color{red}{-}\exp\left(\frac{\log(1.08)}{1200}\right)-1,$$
which can be equivalently written as 
$$x=\color{red}{-}\sqrt[1200]{1.08}-1.$$

Comment: and 1198 other complex solutions with non-zero imaginary part...

Comment: Although you are most definitely correct, the fact that the exponent is even does play a role qhen considering real solutions only, so I wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are interested in method how to find the decimals?

So you have $$x=exp(\frac{log 1.08}{1200})-1$$
You can use Taylor series(google it...)
$$Log1.08=0+0.08-0.0032+...~=0.077$$
Divide by 1200... ~= 0.000064
And so on...

Answer (score 0):

$1.08=(1+x)^{1200}$ implies clearly that $x$ must be small, very small indeed but not negative as I believed at the first sight because $a^x\gt 1$ implies $x\ln a\gt 0$ which is not the case. Calculating, as usual with these kind of numbers, one has
$$(1+10^{-4})^{1200}\approx 1.1274900870\\(1+10^{-5})^{1200}\approx 1.0120722814$$ hence $$10^{-5}\lt x\lt 10^{-4}$$ Paying more attention to these calculations, (or, for example, expanding in series) we can get the approximation $\color{red}{x=6.44\cdot 10^{-5}}$ which gives $$(1+6.44\cdot10^{-5})^{1200}\approx 1.0803418422$$